# Not able to access the text from an editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created a really simple app (for Android, using Eclipse) that have an editText and a button. The idea is to make a toast with the text from the editText. After trying a lot of things I have find out the problem is something related with the declaration of the editText.

I have the same problem every time I try to access to an editText and after researching a lot I don't know why.

Here is my code for the MainActivity

```
package com.example.textviewprova;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public void showText(View view)
    {
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Also here it is the fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.textviewprova.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:onClick="showText"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also have the log [Log.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0del1ceg7qzksjz/log.txt)
And the complete project [Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/drktc4qooduzhpi/textViewProva.zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EditText belongs to the fragment

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
        {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v)
              {
                 String text = editText.getText().toString();
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

and you could get rid of  `android:onClick="showText"`

and this

```
public void showText(View view)
{
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Although you can get the value of ediText in Activity also.

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current view hierarchy. You inflate `fragment_main.xml` and the view belongs to the same. But you initialize in Activtiy which causes NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Remove `EditText` initilization from `MainActivity` `OnCreate`

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText editText;
    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public void showText(View view)
{
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: `editText` is declared in Fragment. So its not available in `showText`. out of scope and op has `android:onClick="showText"`

Comment: Yes, by doing that, I have an error in showText because it's not able to recognize the editText.